# Alarm / Alert sound in Android

Tags: android, alert, android-alarms

I am working on an Android project and I want to raise some kind of alert or sound. I have implemented a countdown timer and once the countdown timer stops, an alarm or alert sound should be raised.

Any idea how can I implement this in Android. Is there any particular class I can use for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the notification class.. look here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

if you don't need notification and just wants to play lets say a mp3 file you could use the MediaPlayer class
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

or if you prefer to play a raw audio file you can use the AudioManager together with the SoundPool class from android.media package. do look for examples on the internet heres a good example
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/11/play-foreground-and-background-music.html

good luck with your codes!

Answer (score 0):

The source code for Android's clock/alarm system is available [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git;a=tree;hb=HEAD), maybe that will lead you in the right direction, granted, it might be overkill, but it's the first thing that came to my mind when the "alarm" word was mentioned :) .

Answer (score 0):

create raw folder in your resource and copy your song then
use this code

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mosi.persianbirthday/" + R.raw.tavalod);
```